# Symfony 2 Code Encryption

Tags: encryption, symfony

I am searching a way to secure the code of a bundle/plugin of Symfony. Is there any way to encrypt php code (even only actions) with IonCube, Zend Guard or SourceGuardian?

Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't had a chance to encrypt Symfony2 bundle code but for Symfony1 there was simple trick to achieve that. S1 is scanning files looking for `class MyExampleClass` strings inside and it builds cache info based on that.

To make encrypted source files work with framework you just need to add `class MyExampleClass` as a comment to source file. Like i mention not sure if it works with S2 but its worth trying i guess.

Answer (score -1):

Your programms should work:
IonCube, Zend Guard or SourceGuardian

However if you have the time and are common with regex you also just could write your own.

Replace same values, words (functionnames, variables, classes, etc.) with some random strings and compress the code so that there are no empty lines, spaces.

Only yml files, html, etc. should be untouched.
Could also be possible with some difficult shell command

```
cat *.php | regex(somereqex) | overwrite...
```

Comment: This question is about encryption not obsfucation. Besides that Symfony2 has some specific loaders with cache mechanisms so could be a bit tricky as framework scans files for classes.